# 'names' attribute [4000] must be the same length as the vector [5]

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have been getting an error whenever I try and change the names of the data frames in a list. I think its due to the different lengths between the names that I'm trying to change and the length that is in a data frame. I apologize if this appears to be a duplicate posting. I will delete if that is the case, but I would really appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2010"), dmy("31-12-2013"), by = "days"),1000)
ID <- rep(c("A","B","C", "D", "E"), 100)

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df1 <- df %>% group_split(ID)

l <- list(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I've been able using this to try and change it but I get the error after trying it:

```
for(i in 1: length(df1)){
  names(l) <- unlist(df1[[i]]$ID)
}
```

I am trying to change these values to the ID values:
[image]

```
Error in names(l) <- unlist(df1[[i]]$ID) : 
  'names' attribute [200] must be the same length as the vector [5]
```

Comment: I am not really sure what you want to do. Would you please clarify more? `unlist(df1)` will become a `vector`. Why do you want to assign a `vector` to a "name" of a `list`?

Comment: It doesn't have to be that. My desired output is to have the names in the list `l` in the picture to be assigned the `ID` values, using the `ID` from the `df1` list. In my actual data set, there are too many `ID` values for me to list them out in a `c()` function, so I was hoping to figure out a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setNames` is what you need:

```
setNames(l, unique(df$ID))
```

Output:

```
$A
[1] 1

$B
[1] 2

$C
[1] 3

$D
[1] 4

$E
[1] 5
```

Comment: What alterations would I need to do if `l <- list(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)` and there were multiple components in the list with the same `ID`?

Comment: @JohnHuang in that case you would do: `setNames(l, c(unique(df$ID), unique(df$ID)))`

Comment: I'm sorry to keep adding on to this. I should have been more clear from the start. I guess this would be a more accurate representation of my actual data `l <- list(1,2,4,3,5,5,3,2,4,1)`. The order is more randomized, but each one of these values is linked with an `ID`, so in this case `1` would be with `A`, `2` with `B`, `3` with `C`, etc.  Is there a way that I would be able to link the values with the `ID` so that it would work even when the values are randomized?